# ORA-00904 Is this a platform bug?

Tags: soql, error, oracle

Since the recent update to our sandbox (2015-09-12) I have a unit test that is failing where previously it worked.

I've isolated it to the following condensed example...
Within the Developer Console>Query Editor this works (i.e. I get a result back):

```
SELECT ID,Environment__r.Code__c FROM Case WHERE CaseNumber='00038062' AND Environment__r.Code__c= '2999' AND Site__r.ERP_Customer_ID__c = '82102001~312'
```

When executing the following code via execute anonymous (in the developer console):

```
List<Case> cases = [SELECT ID,Environment__r.Code__c FROM Case WHERE CaseNumber='00038062' AND Environment__r.Code__c= '2999' AND Site__r.ERP_Customer_ID__c = '82102001~312'];
```

I get this error:

```
Line: 1
Column: 1
System.UnexpectedException: common.exception.SfdcSqlException: ORA-00904: "CFT"."VAL52": invalid identifier select /*Apex.AnonymousBlock: line 1*/ /*+     ordered use_nl(cft) */ nest."Id"
cft.val52 "Environment__c"
cft.val14 "Site__c" from (select * from (select * from (select /*+ ordered use_nl(cft_c14) index(cft_c14 PKACCOUNT_CFDATA) use_nl(t_c14) index(t_c14     pkaccount) use_nl(t_c14cfkv) use_nl(t) use_nl(t_c52) index(t_c14cfkv iecustom_foreign_key_value) index(t pkcases) */ t.deleted "IsDeleted_gen_1"
t_c14.deleted "IsDeleted_gen_2"
t_c52.deleted "IsDeleted_gen_3"
t.case_number "CaseNumber"
t_c52.val2 "t_c52_Code__c"
cft_c14.val53 "t_c14_ERP_Customer_ID__c"
ind.string_value "t_c14_ERP_Customer_ID__c.X"
t.cases_id "Id"
t.cases_id repl__0 from core.custom_unique_value ind
sales.account_cfdata cft_c14
sales.account t_c14
core.custom_foreign_key_value t_c14cfkv
support.cases t
core.custom_entity_data t_c52 where (ind.entity_id = cft_c14.account_cfdata_id) 
(t_c14.account_id = cft_c14.account_cfdata_id) 
(t_c14cfkv.entity_id = t.cases_id) 
(t_c14.account_id = t_c14cfkv.foreign_key_id) 
(cft.val52 = t_c52.custom_entity_data_id) 
(ind.organization_id = '00Dg0000006SzCA') 
(ind.key_prefix = ?) 
(ind.deleted = '0') 
(ind.index_num = ?) 
(cft_c14.organization_id = '00Dg0000006SzCA') 
(t_c14.organization_id = '00Dg0000006SzCA') 
(t_c14.account_id != '000000000000000') 
(t_c14cfkv.organization_id = '00Dg0000006SzCA') 
(t_c14cfkv.key_prefix = ?) 
(t_c14cfkv.index_num = ?) 
(t_c14cfkv.deleted = '0') 
(t.organization_id = '00Dg0000006SzCA') 
(t.cases_id != '000000000000000') 
(t_c52.organization_id = '00Dg0000006SzCA') 
(t_c52.custom_entity_data_id != '000000000000000') 
(t_c52.key_prefix = ?)) where (("IsDeleted_gen_1" = '0') 
("IsDeleted_gen_2" = '0') 
("IsDeleted_gen_3" = '0') 
(upper("CaseNumber") = ?) 
(upper("t_c52_Code__c") = ?) 
(upper("t_c14_ERP_Customer_ID__c") = ?) 
("t_c14_ERP_Customer_ID__c.X" = ?))) where rownum <= ?) nest
support.cases_cfdata cft where (repl__0 = cft.cases_cfdata_id) 
(cft.organization_id = '00Dg0000006SzCA')
```

Not sure what (if anything) could be wrong with this code? (and it's worked until now...))

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, those are platform internal errors. Your best shot will be contacting sfdc support to get this resolved.